# перехват ошибок

Tags: php, ajax

Поясните пожалуйста за работу с ошибками в php

Хочу при появлении ошибок внутри функции их обрабатывать и возвращать информацию об ошибке (на начальных этапах всю инфу в виде html на экран, потом часть прятать в логи). Прочитал о функции set_error_handler, о try catch, но видимо что-то не догоняю как это все работает.

Вот эта конструкция работает как мне нужно, при запуске я получаю то, что ожидаю.

```
function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline){
  echo 'номер '.$errno.', сообщение '.$errstr.', файл '.$errfile.', позиция '.$errline;
  return true;
}

set_error_handler('errorHandler', E_ALL);

$a = array(2, "foo"+2);
print_r($a);
```

Но стоит положить поломанный массив внутрь функции.

```
...

function test($weight){
  $a = array(2, "foo"+2);
  print_r($a);
}
```

Как я начинаю получать при вызове функции `test` стандартный вывод информации об ошибке

> **Warning**:  A non-numeric value encountered in
> **D:\web\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\zinger-eat.ru\function.php** on
> line **117**

Если я правильно понимаю функция `set_error_handler` должна **перехватывать** появляющиеся ошибки (кроме фатальных), но она не перехватывает ошибки, возникающие в функциях?

Окей, чтобы ловить ошибки с помощью try/catch нужно генерить исключения в блоке `try` и обрабатывать их в блоке `catch`, но я ведь не знаю какая может возникнуть именно ошибка при выволнении функции, я и рассчитываю, что перехватчик ошибок мне расскажет, а не я буду продумывать и прописывать все исключения для каждой ситуации.

В общем я немного взволнован, что не могу найти решение и понять как работать с ошибками.

**UPD**: После комментария splash58 я понял, что `set_error_handler` все же перехватывает ошибки корректно и внутри функций, однако в моем проекте проблема сохраняется. Такой код работает как надо

```js
function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
  echo 'номер '.$errno.
  ', сообщение '.$errstr.
  ', файл '.$errfile.
  ', позиция '.$errline;
  return true;
}

set_error_handler('errorHandler', E_ALL);

function test() {
  $a = array(2, "foo" + 2);
  print_r($a);
}

test();
```

Но в своем проекте я с помощью ajax обращаюсь к файлу php, где у меня написано несколько функций и вызываю нужную мне функцию с помощью `call_user_func_array`. В этом случае ошибка, возникшая в этой функции, не перехватывается `set_error_handler`. К сожалению не знаю как предоставить пример из песочницы где можно было бы разместить и Php часть и javascript, все до чего я додумался это скрин с кусками кода, который я сваял, прости господи, в power point

https://ibb.co/0DXNqnx

Может сообществу будет достаточно этой скудной информации, чтобы указать в чем у меня проблема, почему ошибки не перехватываются.

**UPD2**: Проблему удалось решить, поместив `set_error_handler` внутрь обрабатываемой функции. Видимо так придется поступать с каждой функцией внутри файла function.php, где я хочу перехватывать ошибки.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.exceptions.php

Comment: При всем моем уважении, я написал, что прочитал про исключения и функцию пользовательской обработки ошибок. Вы предлагаете мне перечитать еще несколько раз документацию? Да, возможно я что-то не понял из документации, может хотя бы цитату кинете, чтобы мне стало стыдно, что я невнимательно прочел? Где-то в документации описано, почему ошибки внутри функции не перехватываются set-error-handler?

Comment: Мне не удалось воспроизвести вашу проблему. все прекрасно перехватилось. php 7.4

Comment: Спасибо, попробовал простейший пример в песочнице - действительно все работает, зря я грешил на некорректный перехват ошибки `set_error_handler`. Обновил вопрос, так как проблема с перехватом ошибок все же сохраняется, но, судя по всему, связана она с чем-то другим

Comment: Вы уверены, что в коде, который вызываете через ajax, вы проходите через назначение обработчика? каждый вызов - это совершенно независимый процесс

Comment: К сожалению не очень понял что вы имеете ввиду. То что каждое обращение к файлу php - отдельный, это я понимаю. Насчет обработчика...функция `postUserWeight` на скрине из вопроса является обработчиком ajax запроса, если я верно понимаю. И раз в итоге я получаю сообщение в консоле об ошибке в массиве, который используется в `postUserWeight`, значит обработчик выполнился.

Comment: У меня ощущение, что проблема именно в обращении к файлу через ajax запрос. Например для авторизации пользователя я использую отдельный скрипт php. И стандартно указываю его в атрибуте `action` формы авторизации. Провоцируя ошибку при авторизации, `set_error_handler` отлично ее ловит. Я даже не знаю в какую сторону копать, я не слышал раньше о проблемах при взаимодействии ajax с php. Может также проблема в том что я при submit'e формы из моего первого кейса я вызываю функцию ajax а сам submit останавливаю return false..но опять же, это может вызывать проблемы?